# Is there a way to append a CSS file with additional styles when needed?

Tags: php, css, compass-sass

I work on a site that pulls in many css files. Some of them are language-specific overrides for international users (We alter some of the styles so longer strings of translated text don't break the layout). So we have something like french.css, spanish.css, etc. When a user clicks on our language switcher, the page reloads with a special class added on the body tag. This is how the page picks up the other styles.

One of our goals in the near future is to only serve our international users the one language-specific file appropriate for them. Right now, everybody gets all the styles even though they aren't necessary. At the same time, one of the managers wants to consolidate our styles into one file to reduce http requests. How can we have one css file without including all our language overrides for every user? Is there a way to append the styles to the one main css file when needed? We use Compass SASS; is there a way to compile different versions of our main file, one that includes Spanish styles, one includes French styles, etc? Ideally, we don't want to have different versions of our main css file in our working directory since we support 25 total languages. Also, our developers use PHP and JavaScript in case anyone has solutions that use these programming languages.

Edit - I should clarify. Is there a script or function that will grab style blocks from one css file and add them directly to another, which would be the one main css file a user is served? This would only execute if a user changes their language choice on our site. Or, since we're using SASS, is there a way in the framework to have the compiler generate 25 css versions of our main.scss, each containing specific language overrides (without having 25 .scss versions in the root of our sass directory)?

Comment: What is the problem with multiple HTTP requests?

Comment: You'll have to ask our manager :) He'll likely tell you to ask his manager.

Comment: You can serve up the main.css to all users and 1 default lang file (EN). The user then selects a different language and using JS, you append that language style sheet to the document? That's 3 different requests. Is that too much?  If you include everything in 1 file, it will have styles for 24 languages they don't need which is a bigger server load than 3 small requests.

Comment: keep the parent class with your language name. Inside the CSS, use language class to differentiate the styles. for ex, all english classes are start with `.english .someclass{styles}`. Like the same way spanish will start with `.spanish .someclass{styles}`. Now we have the same name `.sameclass` in a single file. But it will give different output base on the language settings.

Comment: I'm working with .NET and in this situation we could get the language and append the needed css with a approach like `[lang]-style.css`, then you wouldn't have to do `if`. I suggest you read up on something like this to get the minification and such for css file and request reduction. http://robertnyman.com/2010/01/19/tools-for-concatenating-and-minifying-css-and-javascript-files-in-different-development-environments/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that using php.
You need to create a php file that will include all of your css and include it in your index file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css_file.php">
```

Then you have to create the css_file.php and use the folowing code:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

// get the language variable from url
$language = $_GET['langvar'];

if($language == "en"){
    // english language css code goes here
    echo "
    body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    ";
} else if($language == "fr"){
    // french language css code goes here
    echo "
    body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    ";
} else if($language == "other"){
    // other language css code goes here
    echo "
    body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    ";
}
?>
```

**Edit:**

If language variable doesn't exist in your code you could get language from session:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

    // get the language variable from active session
    $language = $_SESSION['langvar'];

    if($language == "en"){
        // english language css code goes here
        echo "
        body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        ";
    } else if($language == "fr"){
        // french language css code goes here
        echo "
        body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        ";
    } else if($language == "other"){
        // other language css code goes here
        echo "
        body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        ";
    }
    ?>
```

**Edit:**

If you want to load separate css files you need to add the following php code to your index file:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // get the language variable from active session
    $language = $_SESSION['langvar'];

    if($language == "en"){
        // english css file load
        echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"english.css\">";
    } else if($language == "fr"){
        // french css file load
        echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"french.css\">";
    } else if($language == "other"){
        // other css file load
        echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"other.css\">";
    }
    ?>
```

If the language session name is the same with css file you could use this:

```
<?php
        session_start();

        // get the language variable from active session
        $language = $_SESSION['langvar'];

        echo "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"".$language.".css\">";
        ?>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP, so forgive me if I'm misunderstanding, but our url doesn't have a language variable. If the user changes their language, "&from=locale-changed" is added to the url briefly, then the page refreshes with translated text and the aforementioned is removed from the url. However, the lang attribute is added to the html element (and sometimes the locale attribute), and a specific class is added to the body tag as well. Is there a way to utilize these instead of the language variable?

Comment: You have to ask your php developer how your system handle the language change. I have edited the code to get language variable from the session if it doesn't exist in the url. Hope this will help you.

Comment: This looks promising! Is it possible to import a css file rather than echoing style blocks? In addition to our main css file, we have separate files with specific overrides for each language; can we use `@import url;` instead? Having the separate files makes it easier for our css developers to maintain.

Comment: Thank you! I will run this by our PHP guys.